# How did this variable increase in its value? - Code Objective C

Tags: c

I am currently doing a learning C from a tutorial from a book and I am following this code.

What I do not understand is how does the variable `numberOfBottles` start from 1 and ends with 4 on this line. Thanks for the help guys, I am still new to Objective C

```
printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles);


void singSongFor(int numberOfBottles)
{
    if (numberOfBottles == 0) {
        printf("There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");
    } else {

        printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall. %d bottles of beer.\n",     numberOfBottles, numberOfBottles);
        int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;

        printf("Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n", oneFewer);
        singSongFor(oneFewer); //This function calls itself!

        // Print a mesasge just before the function ends

        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // We could sing 99 verses, ut 4 is easier to think about
    singSongFor(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It goes from 4 to 1.  What do you mean by "this line"?

Comment: I was wondering how the variable numberOfBottles would have a value of 1 and adds + 1 for every sentence?

Hi so the ending would be:

    Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.
    Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.
    Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin.
    Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.
    Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: @Avi he is talking about  printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method is calling itself recursively after subtracting one from its argument integer. so the method will run five times, first with an argument of `4`, then `3`, `2`, `1`, then `0` when it enters the `if` and ceases to call itself any more

Comment: Once it ceases itself, how does the variable numberOfBottles get a value of 1 and increases its value back to 4 as I did not define it to be +1 as the song repeats and ends with 


Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin. 
Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin. 
Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin. 
Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin. 
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: The final print statement for each iteration of the recursion doesn't run until the innermost call reaches the `if` statement and completes, then each previous call continues and completes, stepping out from the innermost call (with `0`) to the outermost call (with `4`)

Comment: oh thanks, I thought it would have ended at 0? Is it because it has to do with the stack?

Comment: i don't know if the term "stack" applies, it's a recursion tree. it's a method call within a method call within a method call within a method call within a method call, so none of them complete until the innermost one does. the illusion of addition is really just the print statements running with their own arguments in each scope that was created during the recursion process

Comment: recursion is a tough concept! glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Put breakpoints and try to understand execution of this snippet, you will get how it works.

When I tried this snippet, it will execute like :

```
4 bottles of beer on the wall. 4 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.

3 bottles of beer on the wall. 3 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

2 bottles of beer on the wall. 2 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on the wall.

1 bottles of beer on the wall. 1 bottles of beer.
Take one down, pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall.

There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.

Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.
Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.
Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin.
Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the recursion.

You start by calling `singSongFor(4)`, which prints "4 bottles of beer..." etc. until it reaches the line `singSongFor(oneFewer);`.

There it calls `singSongFor(3)`, which prints "3 bottles of beer" and calls `SingSongFor(2)`... and then `singSongFor(1)` and lastly `singSongFor(0)`.

`singSongFor(0)` only prints "There are simply no bottles" and ends,

then `singSongFor(1)` continues running and prints "... 1 empty bottles..." and ends,

then `singSongFor(2)` continues and prints "2 empty bottles",

then `singSongFor(3)` prints "3 empty bottles"

and finally the starting function call `singSongFor(4)` continues and prints "4 bottles" and ends.

The point of the recursion here is that when the function calls itself, it pauses and runs the newly called function and so on until it reaches a point where it doesnt make a recursive call. Then it starts going back again to the previous functions and continues them until they end.

Comment: Thanks George, does that mean than once singSongFor(0) happens, the value will automatically go back to singSongFor(1)? I was trying to figure how the numberOfBottles variable was given the Value of +1.

Unless of course recursion makes it go from 4 to 0 then back to 4. Is that how it works?

Comment: Yes exactly. Song(4)->Song(3)->Song(2)->Song(1)->Song(0)->Song(1)->Song(2)->Song(3)->Song(4) could be a representation of the recursion here.

Comment: Somehow my answer isnt helpful anymore?

Comment: sorry george, I would tick all of your answers if I could.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding this you have to understand recursion. Here you method

```
void singSongFor(int numberOfBottles
```

is recursive method as it calls itself inside method body.So what is happening here:
when you call `singSongFor(4);` in main function.
it checks the if condition, as 4 is not equal to zero,it goes in else part and prints both `printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall. %d bottles of beer.\n",     numberOfBottles, numberOfBottles);`  and `printf("Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n", oneFewer);` but before printing the last line that you are talking about, the method calls itself `singSongFor(oneFewer);`. and the execution of `printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles);` put into a stack when number of bottles is 4 and this keep on going until numberOfBottles == 0.When this happens If part execute and the stack containing `printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles);` is popped off. At the top of stack this statment has numberOfBottles 1,next 2,next 3 and lastone 4.

Comment: once singsongfor(0) shouldn't numberOfBottles have a value of 0 instead of 1? for the part where it is printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles); ?

Comment: @RaphaelLim when numberOfBottles = 1, onefewer will be 0 and then there is call to singsongfor(0). but numberOfBottles is still one for the printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n", numberOfBottles);

Answer (score 0):

Remember!

> To undestand recursion you have to understand recursion first.